# -too for object to infinitive (object)-

Tags: grammar

#### The box is too heavy for me to lift it.

#### The box is too heavy for me to lift.

> I want to know whether I need to put ***object
>    in *too for object to infinitive * structure.

Comment: It's entirely your choice - which won't affect the meaning one way or the other. But [most people don't include "it"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22too+heavy+for+me+to+lift%22+-%22for+me+to+lift+it%22) (that's over 3000 hits in Google Books, compared to just 123 for [the longer version](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22too+heavy+for+me+to+lift+it%22)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The longer version has only one obvious hit (in *Ключі. Типові проблеми англійського слововживання. [англ./укр.].: Ключі до вправ*). The rest are either false positives or inconclusive results (we can't see the texts).

Comment: @Damkerng T.: That suggests referring back to the original noun with a pronoun like this is even less common than I thought, but I still wouldn't say it's exactly "non-idiomatic" to do so in OP's *exact* context. On the other hand, if we discard ***for me***, I'm inclined to think something like *My car is too heavy to lift **it*** would be ***so*** unlikely I'd be happy to say that's non-idiomatic.

Comment: This is ungrammatical:  *The box is too heavy to lift it*.  Does adding **for me** to the sentence make **it** grammatical? I don't think so. I would consider it "marginal".

Comment: I agree with TRomano. The doer of the infinitive is almost always implied based on the context. In _The box is too heavy to lift_ it's generally implied _for anyone_. _For me_  just makes more specific and I don't think it makes it acceptable to insert the object. I suppose there are some cases where subject and object refers to the same thing or person which lets us use a reflexive pronoun esp. for emphasis as in _he's too heavy to move himself around_.